# Using firebase in an ionic/ karma/ jasmine test

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to do a basic firebase set call in an ionic / jasmine/ karma/ test but my set never runs . .. I'm also including firebase and angularfire in my karma.conf file, can anyone offer any advice on this please!

```
  beforeEach(function() {
                module('avocado.controllers');
                module("firebase");
            });

  describe('controller variables', function() {
            it('should contain the AvoDB service', function() {
                var AvoDB =  new Firebase("https://devdev.firebaseio.com/somechild");
                console.log('avodb', AvoDB);
                AvoDB.set('123456');
                expect(AvoDB).toBeDefined();
            })
```